# Change connection string dynamically

Tags: python, fastapi

So I have this code:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};"
                                     "SERVER=DESKTOP-90423MF;"
                                     "DATABASE=patients;" 
                                     "UID=sa;"
                                    "PWD=randompass")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
print(pyodbc.drivers())
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

And in my endpoint, I'm using get_db like this:

```
@app.get("/{patient_id}/{file_no}/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get_patient_report(patient_id: str, file_no: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

And that's working fine, but I can't seem to find a way to dynamically change the connection string?

I want to add `{x}` to the endpoint parameters and then, use that parameter to request the correct DB.

So for example if `x = 05`, I should be requesting `patients_05`
If I simply add x to the parameters of the function, as well as the endpoint, I still won't be able to send it to get_db, it would still say it's undefined. So what's a workaround?

Comment: You probably want to define a list of valid databases instead of trusting user input directly; but you can either use `create_engine` for each request and wrap it in a lru cache or something similar, or set up all possible values at the start of your connection and create an engine for each database - if the number of databases are on the smaller side, that would probably work just fine.

Comment: It might help to know from where you will source the `x` value, so that you know when you need to choose the database connection.